# Getting Error When trying to play Counter strike 1.6

Tags: steam, technical-issues, counter-strike

Everything was fine, but after a 123 MB update of Steam, I tried to connect to a server and it says "Cannot continue without script events/awp.sc, disconnecting."  I get the same for every server.

I saw some files that gets downloaded when entering the first time in the server after the update:

- gign.mdl - which I think should have been there before as its the model
- galil.something - It's the clarion type which should not be downloaded again as it gets installed before.

Could not launch new game also as the process is exiting.

I am Using Ubuntu 13.10.
Steam icon before this was normal with square shaped and valve symbol within it.after the update it becomes round with blue colour.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried verifying the local game cache?

Comment: lastly i have  to delete game content and then reinstall cs again

Comment: If you fixed it by reinstalling the game, you can post an answer to your own question and mark as solved.